# Macbook Pro audio stops working too often

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, sound-volume

When I'm working on my 2017 Macbook Pro with 10.14.6, the audio often stops working. I can hear only beep of Siri, nothing else, no Youtube sound, no Skype call sound, no zoom sound, etc.

In Sound output tab everything is correct, the issue is fixed only when I restart my laptop.

Any idea what's happening? This issue is driving me insane.

Comment: What model/year of MBP?  What macOS version?

Comment: @fsb 2017 Macbook pro, Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Isn't it fixed as well if you quit and restart all audio related processes?

Answer (score 1):

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

If your Mac has issues related to settings stored in NVRAM or PRAM, resetting it might help. Sound also comes under this section, so I strongly suggest you to try this as after reboot your MacBook is getting normal.

**How to reset NVRAM**

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

[image]

1. On Mac computers that play a startup sound, you can release the keys after the second startup sound.
2. On Mac computers that have the Apple T2 Security Chip, you can release the keys after the Apple logo appears and disappears for the second time

When your Mac finishes starting up, you might want to open System Preferences and adjust any settings that were reset, such as sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, or time zone.